# ggplot label contours with sf object

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf

I have a contour dataset imported using `st_read()` from a shapefile. I have plotted this using `ggplot()` and `geom_sf()`. It renders nicely. Now I want to label the contours. Using `geom_st_label()` does not produce great output. Contours are dense in places and labels overlap.

I had a look at the `metR` package. This has a `geom_contour_label()` function that controls contour placement nicely in `ggplot()`. However, the `geom_contour()` and associated functions do not recognise the geometry contained in sf_objects. I get this error: `stat_contour requires the following missing aesthetics: x, y and z`.

How can I get `geom_contour_label()` to work with an sf object? This is what `geom_contour_label()` can produce:

[image]

My contour data is available from https://cloudstor.aarnet.edu.au/sender/?s=download&token=241de91b-2015-4a19-a18f-c2125a12f2a7.

```
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)

isobath <- read_sf("1misobath.shp")

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = isobath, color = "blue", lwd = 0.25) +
  geom_sf_label(data = isobath, aes(label = DEPTH), size = 2) +
  coord_sf(xlim = c(18.42, 18.5), ylim = c(-34.20, -34.16), expand = T) +
  theme_bw()
```

Comment: Hi @aterhorst. Don't know if I can help you but for the moment I can't download the file ;-)

Comment: Fixed download link.

Comment: I looked at `st_coordinates()` and can extract XY coordinates plus a corresponding line-string identifier. Why `geom_contour()` is unable to handle sf objects is puzzling.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I will look into this tomorrow in detail (currently, it is very late in France, my neurons are disconnected!!). Cheers.

Comment: Hi @aterhorst. After a few hours of thorough examination/testing, I think I have found a satisfactory solution to your mapping problem (cf. answer below). I hope it will meet your wishes. Cheers.

Comment: Thank you very much. I appreciate the effort you put in to help me. Hopefully, others will benefit from your solution too!

Comment: Glad that I coul help you. I wish you all the best in your work. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After examining the `geom_contour()` function in depth. Here is my understanding of the problem.

The function `geom_contour()` does not expect an object of type `sf` but a `dataframe` or a `data.table` which contains rows of points (not linestrings as in your case) with three columns: longitude (i.e. X), latitude (i.e. Y) and a Z column (i.e., in your case, this would be the variable `DEPTH`). The `geom_contour()` function will then compute the isolines and plot them on the map.

From your `sf` object, I was able to create a dataframe of points with X, Y and Z coordinates as the function expects, but then I was faced with an unsolvable problem. The grid of your data is `rectilinear`, but the function expects a grid of `regular` type. So, to convert the grid from `rectilinear` to `regular`, I tried to interpolate the points with the `interp()` function of the `akima` package but it was impossible because of the duplicated values in Z (i.e. variable `DEPTH`).

So I changed my mind! And finally, I think I found a very simple solution to your mapping problem by using the `tm_iso()` function of the very good `tmap` package.

Please find the reprex below showing the code and the resulting map result.

**Reprex**

```r
library(sf) 
library(s2)
library(tmap)

# 1. Your data
isobath <- st_read("D:/test/Projet_essai4/Isobath/1misobath.shp")
#> Reading layer `1misobath' from data source 
#>   `D:\test\Projet_essai4\Isobath\1misobath.shp' using driver `ESRI Shapefile'
#> Simple feature collection with 162 features and 9 fields
#> Geometry type: LINESTRING
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 18.43944 ymin: -34.19143 xmax: 18.49996 ymax: -34.16805
#> Geodetic CRS:  Cape


# 2. Visualization of your data with tm_iso() of the tmap package
tm_shape(isobath) +
  tm_grid(col ="lightgray", line = TRUE) +
  tm_iso(col = "blue", text = "DEPTH",  fontface = "bold") +
  tm_layout(frame = TRUE, inner.margins = 0)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-10-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

- Another version, perhaps closer to what you are looking for:

```r
tm_shape(isobath) +
  tm_grid(col ="white", line = TRUE) +
  tm_iso(col = "blue", text = "DEPTH",  fontface = "bold", bg.color = "lightgray", shadow = TRUE, size = 0.6) +
  tm_layout(bg.color = "lightgray", frame = TRUE, inner.margins = 0)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-10-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>